# Giving an Apache server rights to access web pages generated by BOINC to get ride of 403 Forbidden

Tags: web, apache2, apache2.2, boinc

[I'm a newbie when it comes to apache or BOINC so bear with any stupid mistakes I make]

**What I have:**

1. A successfully built BOINC server in
   /home/local/srinivas/projects/tesla
2. A working apache2 server
   [version 2.2]

**What is the problem:**

The php and html files generated by the BOINC server are not servable by apache and I keep getting a 403 error. Manually copying the files to /var/ helpse me see the pages but they don't function as expected and this seems hacky

So I followed the guide on the boinc serverpage to make a server. I just need to get apache2 to access the files in my home folder.

**What I tried**

1. making a symlink to my project folder in /var/www
2. changing the owner of my project folder to www-data

Bot these approaches didn't work. Can someone give me some pointers?

Comment: did you added a default document to your virtual host configuration to fit with your project default page ?

Comment: actually it was because I used "sudo" to run some scripts that did not allow apache to serve the generated files. I fixed it by adding apache to the sudoers